# How do I make a C++ int array loop that will not allow repeated values?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, input, int

I need a loop that will keep asking for input until there isn't a repeated value in the array. When I run my code it will recognize that there is a duplicate but it will go through the rest of my code and not ask for input again. I've tried this many different ways so any insight is greatly appreciated

```
cout << "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values: ";
for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
    cin >> d[x];
}

while (duplicateTest(d))
{
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        cin >> d[x];
    }
}



bool duplicateTest (int d[])
{
int i, j;
bool duplicate;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < 10 + 1; j++)
    {
        if (d[i] == d[j])
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry, do not repeat values." << endl
                 << "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values: " << endl;  
            duplicate = true;
        }
        else 
            duplicate = false;

    }
}

return duplicate;
```

Comment: Use a counter, not a for loop in the input while loop.  The duplicate test should limit the for loop to the number of elements that are currently in the data.
Ask yourself if you want the user to have to start over from scratch when they enter a duplicate or do you just want to tell them and keep going until they have 10 unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `duplicateTest` function should be rewritten to return `true` as soon as it finds a single duplicate:

```
bool duplicateTest(int (&d)[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
            if (d[i] == d[j]) {
                std::cout << "Invalid entry, do not repeat values\n"
                             "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values:\n";
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}
```

As it is right now it sets `duplicate` to `true` when it finds a duplicate but then it will probably set it back to `false` during a later iteration when some `d[i]` `d[j]` pair is not a duplicate

I had to do a bit of work to make your code able to compile, below is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

bool duplicateTest(int (&d)[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
            if (d[i] == d[j]) {
                std::cout << "Invalid entry, do not repeat values\n"
                             "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values:\n";
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int d[10];

    std::cout << "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cin >> d[i];

    while (duplicateTest(d))
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            std::cin >> d[i];

    std::cout << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `duplicateTest()` After you set `duplicate = true` you need to return. Consider `[0]` and `[1]` are the same. You'll set `duplicate = true` then compare `[1]` and `[2]` which are different so `duplicate` will go back to `false`.  Once you have found a duplicate you can stop looking - you don't care how many dupes you have.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you are overwriting the duplicate flag in duplicateTest().

```
    cout << "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values: ";
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        cin >> d[x];
    }

    while (duplicateTest(d))
    {
        cout << "Duplicate value found. Enter 10 integers with no repeated values: ";
        for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            cin >> d[x];
        }
    }



bool duplicateTest (int d[])
{
    int i, j;
    bool duplicate = false; //Better to initialize.
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10 + 1; j++)
        {
            if (d[i] == d[j])
            {
                cout << "Invalid entry, do not repeat values." << endl
                     << "Enter 10 integers with no repeated values: " << endl;  
                duplicate = true;
                break; //If you detect at least one duplicate, exit the loop.
            }
            else 
                duplicate = false;

        }
        if(duplicate) break; //Break the outerloop.
    }

    return duplicate;
}
```

Comment: Just providing a wall of code with no explanation of what you fixed is not a good answer. - Plus you still have bugs - once you find a duplicate you need to break both loops not just the inner one. Easier to `return`

Comment: Agreed. Actually i had added the explanation in comments. Anyway thanks for the feedback. :)